# Leonardo soft bricked

Tags: arduino-leonardo

I was uploading a sketch to my Arduino Leonardo and I pressed the reset button accidentally while it was still uploading. Now the board does not get recognized by my computer. Is there something that can be done to save it or should I get a new one?

Comment: activate the bootloader with reset or double reset and upload a working sketch while the bootloader is active

Comment: There's no COM port to send the sketch to, even after double reset. How can I upload a sketch when there's no board recognized?

Comment: If you can no longer activate the bootloader, even with the double reset method, then it looks like you will have to reinstall the bootloader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to program it trough the ISP port with an AVR programmer if you can't program it through a reset or double reset anymore. This can be done using another arduino. A tutorial is on the [arduino.cc website](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP).

Comment: Thank you I will try that.